# PHP associative array: special character?

Tags: mysql, arrays, count, associative

I have this `MySQL` selection query :

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) 
  FROM $database 
  GROUP BY country
```

The output is an associative array with many rows and two columns:   `[country]`,`[COUNT(*)]`

Now I would like to print them out all BUT with

```
 if (count($results) > 0) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
      echo "country: " . $results[$x]->country. "<br>";
      echo "reads:   " . $results[$x]**[COUNT()]**. "<br>";
    }
 } else {
    echo "0 results";
 }
```

It seems the code does not recognize `COUNT(*)` as column name and get no results. How can I access this second column values?

Comment: I realize editor missed " * " in betwenn COUNT commas .... maybe something similar occurs to my PHP code ?

Answer (score 1):

Add alias (name) to your query field for `COUNT(*)`
like:

`SELECT country, COUNT(*) as my_count FROM $database GROUP BY country`

and call it in your php code by name:

```
 if (count($results) > 0) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo "country: " . $results[$x]->country. "<br>";
    echo "reads:   " . $results[$x]->my_count. "<br>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$results[$x]->country` is object notation.  Is `$results[$x]` an array or an object?  They are not the same thing.  I'm not sure what `$results[$x]**[COUNT()]**` is meant to be but adding asterisks around the key will definitely break things.

For array, you can use:

```
$results[$x]['COUNT(*)']
```

or for object:

```
$results[$x]->{'COUNT(*)'}
```

`COUNT(*)` should be a valid key for either but you need to enclose it in quotes.

Comment: I'll try this as well. Thanks a lot.